# Compile-time method call validation for multiple parameters of the same type

Tags: c#, methods, compiler-errors

Here is demonstration of the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static double Func(double a, double b) { return a * 1000 + b * b; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = 1.1d;
        var b = 2.2d;
        Console.WriteLine(Func(a, b));
        // this is the problem, function doesn't recognize when a and b
        // "accidentally" exchanged, target is to make this row a compile-time error
        Console.WriteLine(Func(b, a));
    }
}
```

This become an issue if there are methods with many parameters (e.g. ten of `double` type):

```
double Func(double parameter1, double parameter2, ..., double parameter10);
```

Question: is there a way to validate parameters when calling method, so that programmer is less prone to do a mistake?

---

This is not an issue if parameter types are different. I thought what maybe *wrapping* into new types will help:

```
class A
{
    private double _value;
    public static implicit operator A(double value) { return new A() { _value = value }; }
    public static implicit operator double(A value) { return value._value; }
}
class B
{
    private double _value;
    public static implicit operator B(double value) { return new B() { _value = value }; }
    public static implicit operator double(B value) { return value._value; }
}

class Program
{
    static double Func(A a, B b) { return a * 1000 + b * b; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = 1.1d;
        B b = 2.2d;
        Console.WriteLine(Func(a, b));
        Console.WriteLine(Func(b, a)); // compile-time error! yay!
        Console.WriteLine(Func(a, b) + 123.123d - a * 2); // implicit conversion power
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And it does, but I am quite unsure if this method is efficient. I have doubts if this is a good idea at all. Is it? Or is there better one?

I know what I can be absolutely safe if I always call method like this (using [named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) method call)

```
Func(a:a, b:b);
```

This shouldn't bring any overhead in code, but a lot of typing. Wrapping is better because it is done once (creating new type is easy), but it probably has overhead.

Comment: If you have ten parameters, you may wrap each group of related parameters in a single type, have you consider that?

Comment: Probably the only way to ensure that you won't give wrong argument is to have different types for **each** parameter and **never** use them in their unwrapped form. It will mostly close one possible avenue of making mistakes. Whether it is a realistic approach or not, and whether it can really improve defect per line ratio and maintainability for the whole program is [another question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/281827/should-we-define-types-for-everything).

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz, good idea. Sounds like an answer to me, I just have to thought about it, give me some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two arguments are of the same type, it's not possible to detect at compile-time, run-time or otherwise that the name of the argument variable corresponds to the name of the parameter. This is kind of an open question, but I will offer you a couple ideas.

- As Mehrzad suggested, consider grouping parameters by some type. For example, instead of `double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)`, consider `double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)`
- In general, if your method has more than 4-5 parameters, consider refactoring. Maybe your method is trying to do too many things and the logic can be divided?
- If what you actually want to do is to perform some check such as ensuring that `a < b`, consider looking into [Code contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You could also use `Debug.Assert()`, but this only works at run-time.
- I wouldn't recommend the kind of implicit conversion you propose. For me, it feels hacky and unintuitive that `A a = 1.1` should have no semantic purpose other than compile-time checking parameters. Your ultimate goal is to make code more maintainable overall.

Comment: Grouping is a good idea, but not really applicable in my real case. Refactoring is not really possible as this method has to be called in many places, some parameters can be properties of some object or has to be specified. In fact I can always demand creating the object for the method (as per answer of @AydinAdn) or rather making method non-static (so before calling method I have to create an instance and during creation fill properties which are then used in method). And regarding last note, consider using `Func(a, 123);`, where `B` is transparently `double`. But yes, I also feel it hacky.

Comment: What does your method do, exactly? It's not good to have methods with many named parameters, but sometimes it's inevitable. Could you maybe at least post the signature of your method?

Comment: Methods are used to calculate statistical value by using given array of data and many more parameters, lets call them configurations, some of them belong to static configuration, some to data-specific dynamic and some adjust the method results itself (doesn't belong to either of configurations). I want to have formula in one place (obviously) and I don't want to pass complete configurations into method (coupling with dynamic configuration is not smart), that's why I preferred nameless entitiless `double` parameters.

Comment: I think to stay with idea which comment of @MehrzadChehraz gave me: remove static methods and make them a part of configuration. I will either call method by using current configuration instance (which has all properties set already) or create a new configuration, set needed properties and then call method. Sounds like removing parameters as a whole.

Comment: I wouldn't advise running using global configuration - it will have maintainability issues in the future. Passing a configuration object seems like a good choice to me

Answer (score 2):

You should never have 10 parameters for a method.

Once you have around 4 parameters, begin to consider the use of a new class to contain those parameters... As an example, consider the preferences of a user navigating on a website...

```
void Main()
{
    UserPreferences preference = new UserPreferences
    {
        BackgroundColor = "#fff",
        ForegroundColor = "#000",
        Language = "en-GB",
        UtcOffSetTimeZone = 0
    };

    User aydin = new User(preference);
}

public class User
{
    public User(UserPreferences preferences)
    {
        this.Preferences = preferences;
    }

    public UserPreferences Preferences { get; set; }
}

public class UserPreferences
{
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    public int UtcOffSetTimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Making a dedicated type to hold arguments for a method is good idea. If however there are many of such cases it is not anymore. In given example `UserPreferences` is a property of `User`. There is no really need to create `UserPreference` type specifically for constructing object, they could be properties of `User` and filled after constructing, unless you are using `UserPreferences` type elsewhere (e.g. to copy preferences from one user to another, would be more elegant compared to copying properties values).

Comment: Yes you wouldn't need a `UserPreference` object to create a `User` in the real world, but it's much more elegant than having a constructor with 4 parameters, I just wanted to share the concept its self

Answer (score 0):

Use an inherited class something like this

```
    class Program
    {
        static double Func(List<Parent> l) { return l[0]._value * 1000 + l[1]._value * l[1]._value; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = 1.1d;
            B b = 2.2d;
            Console.WriteLine(Func(new List<Parent>() {a,b}));
            Console.WriteLine(Func(new List<Parent>() { a, b })); // compile-time error! yay!
            Console.WriteLine(Func(new List<Parent>() { a, b }) + 123.123d - a * 2); // implicit conversion power
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Parent
    {
        public double _value { get; set; }
    }
    class A : Parent
    {
        public static implicit operator A(double value) { return new A() { _value = value }; }
        public static implicit operator double(A value) { return value._value; }
    }
    class B : Parent
    {
        public static implicit operator B(double value) { return new B() { _value = value }; }
        public static implicit operator double(B value) { return value._value; }
    }
```

Comment: I have turned code snippet into code block - Runnable code snippets only make sense for questions with HTML, CSS, or JavaScript - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent.